# Issues with jQuery, ajax, and jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am using jsonp and ajax to access a web service on another server. Here's the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: wsurl + 'callback=?',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  error: function(data) {
    console.log('error', data);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success', data);
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('done');
  }
});
```

The issue is that the error callback is being called. It gives me this wonderfully helpful information:

```
{
  readyState: 4,
  status: 200,
  statusText: "success"
}
```

And here is the json file I am calling:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "room_number": "0",
  "first_name": "Admin",
  "last_name": "Istrator",
  "password": "",
  "salutation": "Mr.",
  "telephone": "",
  "email": "",
  "description": "admin",
  "checkin_date": 915797106000,
  "checkout_date": 4071557106000,
  "last_login_date": 947333106000,
  "active_status": true,
  "created_date": 915797106000,
  "created_by": 0,
  "reference_id": ""
}
```

I tried using the getJSON jQuery method first, with the same result. Thought I'd try the base ajax method, since it has a bit more control, but as you can see, no luck. So, notice anything I'm doing wrong? Have any idea why it is throwing an error and giving me a successful value for the statusText property?

### EDIT

Alright, I added some options to the ajax call, and removed the callback param from the url. Here's the new ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: wsurl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

I'm getting a new error, which is good I suppose, but still not working. Difference is that the textStatus is now "parsererror". The console is also throwing a syntax error on line one of the json file:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Ideas?

Comment: All looks fine to me if that's any consolation... Would it be possible for you to set up an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Is the server configured to handle JSONP-type requests?

Comment: It should be. At least, the server-side guy says it is.

Comment: I created a sample http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/2vk3J/ note the different error function and you might, for your live site need to pass empty data as `data:"{}", and add a contentType: in there as well as fix the url issue others noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay a couple of things jump out at me:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  #You do not need to append the callback as you have jsonp configured it will  do it    
  #automatically append the callback=<auto generated name>
  url: wsurl, 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  error: function(data) {
    console.log('error', data);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success', data);
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('done');
  }
});
```

Also your return does not to appear to be wrapped in a function which is required for jsonp to work.

```
<auto generated name>({ json object })
```

The callback function will be named by jquery automatically.  So you need a service that will take in a callback parameter and return a json object with padding.

Comment: I removed the callback from the url, but I'm not sure what you mean with wrapping he return in a function. You mean a function besides the error, success, and complete callbacks?

Comment: The whole point of jsonp is that a json object returned from a cross domain is not allowed, but when wrapped in a function it is allowed.  You should read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Quite correct sir, thanks for the information. Works splendidly now. :)

Comment: Glad it helped.  I got stuck on that too when I first started using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but your url is not correct.  According to the jQuery docs, it should automatically append the ?callback=? for you:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If I take away the question mark at the end, I run into the access control allow origin protocol issue.

Comment: what if you just do this for the url -- url: wsurl

Comment: If not that, then try adding the question mark at the beginning as well like this -- url: wsurl + ?callback=?

Comment: It does, you're right. I assumed it needed it since $.getJSON needed it to know I wanted jsonp. No change in the results though.

Comment: Are you sure your server is expecting the parameter to be called callback?  Is it something else like jsonp_callback or something?  In that case, you need to set the jsonp property to be the name of the callback parameter they're expecting:

jsonp: 'callback_name'

Comment: Yes, when I go to it in browser, appending '?callback=?' works like a charm.

Comment: Don't append the callback, jQuery will do that on it's own. You just have to reformat your json a little bit. Look at my answer to see how to format.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the callback from the URL and try and wrap your json with something like this (php example, $_GET['callback'] is automatically set by jQuery):

```
$_GET['callback'] . '({
  "id": 0,
  "room_number": "0",
  "first_name": "Admin",
  "last_name": "Istrator",
  "password": "",
  "salutation": "Mr.",
  "telephone": "",
  "email": "",
  "description": "admin",
  "checkin_date": 915797106000,
  "checkout_date": 4071557106000,
  "last_login_date": 947333106000,
  "active_status": true,
  "created_date": 915797106000,
  "created_by": 0,
  "reference_id": ""
})'
```

Comment: Can't, I don't have access to the json.

Comment: That's going to be a problem then. The return as you have it is not properly formatted jsonp. It has to be wrapped to work as jsonp because jquery requires it. Check out this tutorial: http://www.using-jquery.com/2011/02/jquery-and-jsonp-cross-domain-requests-in-jquery/