# PhoneGap Issues with ajax and jsonp

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, jsonp, ripple

I want to issue an AJAX call to my remote server, upload a few parameters and download some content. This script works perfectly in a browser, but doesn't work with PhoneGap (testing on Ripple, chrome).

I have looked at problems and solutions such as:

[PhoneGap not issuing AJAX (jsonp) request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333895/phonegap-not-issuing-ajax-jsonp-request)

[Issues with jQuery, ajax, and jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087034/issues-with-jquery-ajax-and-jsonp)

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://mydomain.com/file.php",
        data: {test:"test"},    
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){
            if(data['var'] == 'correct'){ 
                notifyAlert('correct','Login');
            }else{
                notifyAlert('incorrect','Login');
            }       
        },          
        error: function(x,e){
            if(x.status==0){
                notifyAlert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.', 'Error');
            }else if(x.status==404){
                notifyAlert('Requested URL not found.', 'Error');
            }else if(x.status==500){
                notifyAlert('Internel Server Error.', 'Error');
            }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                notifyAlert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed. '+x.status, 'Error');
            }else if(e=='timeout'){
                notifyAlert('Request Time out.');
            }else {
                notifyAlert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText, 'Error');
            }       
        }
    });
```

Remote server code:

```
$record = array('var' => 'correct');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($record) . ');';
```

My config.xml file has:

```
<access origin="https://mydomain.com" />
```

When testing on Ripple (emulator) it gives me the status 0 error. When testing te same script on my local server (through the browser) it gives me the correct var alert.

I also tested a json call and this works perfectly in the emulator but it doesn't work when I upload the apk to my phone. Same result as the problem above with jsonp (status 0 error).

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the Ripple emulator. Tested the same code with eclipse and everything works fine!

It could be the cordova version in Ripple but after testing it with cordova version 2.0.0 it still gave me the status 0 error. The only thing I can think of is that my config.xml is wrong but that doesn't explain the fact that the json test works and the jsonp test doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. It was a problem with my SSL certificate. I tested on a server with a unsigned certificate which gave me the incorrect response. Using a signed certificate resolved all my problems..